# Function Cooldown

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make it so someone can only run a function via a custom menu every 1 minute, when they run the function it will run a function and then make them wait 1 minute before letting them run it again. Here is my entire code:

```
function onOpen(){
  var cooldown = 0;
  DevDisableCD();
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("r/place menu");
  menu.addSeparator();
  menu.addItem("Set Color", "SetColor");
  menu.addItem("Dev { Disable CD", "DevDisableCD");
  menu.addToUi();
};
function DevDisableCD(){
  cooldown <- cooldown - 1;
}
function DisableCD(){
  Utilities.sleep(300000);
  cooldown <- cooldown - 1;
};
function EnableCD(){
  cooldown <- cooldown + 1;
  DisableCD();
};
function SetColor() {
  if(cooldown = 0){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.prompt(
      'Set Color',
      'Please enter your hex color (ie: #000000):',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var cellcolor = result.getResponseText();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('a')
    .activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Place'), true);
    if(cellcolor != ''){
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground(cellcolor);
    EnableCD();
    };
  } else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Your on cooldown!", "You can only color a pixel every minute");
  };
};
```

Edit: Yes I have tried `Utilities.sleep()`

Comment: Do you have a question about your code?

Comment: `cooldown <- cooldown + 1` what is with te `<-`

Comment: No, I am just wondering how I can make it so my current code has the ability to do what I specified above.

Comment: the `<-` is setting the value since app-script uses javascript

Comment: What is the current result of your code?

Comment: The current result of my code is it just always saying that it's on cooldown

Comment: I would suggest logging `cooldown` anytime it's supposed to change and see if it's changing as expected.

Comment: alright i'll try that and get back to you

Comment: It says that the variable 'cooldown' is not defined.

Comment: Makes sense. You initialized it in `onOpen()`, so it's scoped to that function. You could make it global or you'd need to pass it to the other functions that use it.

Comment: Ah ok, ill do that

Answer (score 2):

Mybe use a global variable or some state managers, you can also use lodash or Rxjs.
here a simple global variable solution:

> ```
> let cooldown = false
> const btn = document.getElementById("menu")
>
> btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
>   console.log("inside func", cooldown)
>   setTimeout(() => {
>     cooldown = false
>     console.log("inside setTime", cooldown)
>     // 3 seconds
>   }, 3000)
>   if (!cooldown ) {
>     // rest of function logic
>     console.log("pressed")
>   }
>
>   cooldown = true
> })
> ```

You aren't working in dom:

> 

```
let cooldown = false;
const doSomething = () => {
  console.log('inside func', cooldown);
  setTimeout(() => {
    cooldown = false;
    console.log('inside setTime', cooldown);
    // 3 seconds
  }, 3000);
  if (!cooldown) {
    // do Something here..rest of function logic
    console.log('excuted');
  }
  cooldown = true;
};
```

Comment: The normal stuff seems to be working but, I get the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. Here is my full code using your fix:

Comment: https://pastes.io/flljgq8hst

Comment: document is available in browsers ...that was just an example code .. you need to modify for your need... the key is a global cooldown variable and setTimout inside the function